# the T-split command in linux as opposed to cat?

Tags: linux, pipe, tee

so for a question I have to store both messages of `x` and `y` to `log`, since `y` only exists and `x` does not I used `cat x y &> log` to be able to store both messages. However as the second part my professor wants us to use `tee` to store both messages and output both messages on the screen, i have tried things like `cat x y &> log | tee log`  ,,,  `tee x y &> log` ,,, `log | x y &> log | tee log`  but can't seem to get it to work at all, I even google search how and have absolute no clue, anyone have anything that could help?

Comment: `tee` is a command; `&>` and `|` are both redirection operators.  `tee` never sees the output of `cat` in this case, because you already redirected the output of `cat` to a file.  Try `cat x y | tee log`

Comment: If you don't have anything in file `x` and you don't have anything in file `y` then of course you don't see anything.  Perhaps you meant to use `echo` instead of `cat`.

Comment: Please **read through the answer I linked to**.  (`&>` is not a standard redirection operator, by the way, it is specific to `bash`.)  Anyway `&> filename` means the same thing (in `bash`) as `2>&1  > filename` means in any shell.  What you want to do instead is redirect stderr to the same place as stdout, then pipe stdout into `tee`.  Read the post I linked.

Comment: my apologies i made mistake that earlier comment on `cat x y | tee log` worked fine i found the problem on why it didn't, sorry and thanks for the help.

Comment: @Wildcard: `&> filename` means the same thing (in `bash`) as `> filename 2>&1` (or `2> filename >&2`) ***but not*** `2>&1 > filename ` — that’s different; order matters (and can sometimes be difficult to understand).

Comment: @G-Man, mea culpa, you're right.  Must have been pretty tired when I wrote that to have missed it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your comments correctly, you have something like the following scenario:

- file `y` contains some text
- file `x` doesn't exist
- file `log` doesn't exist (or you don't care if you delete its contents with the command I give you).

You want to have the error message about the nonexistence of file `x` *and* the contents of file `y` both dumped into the file `log`, and you also want this output displayed on your terminal.

If that's all correct, what you want is:

```
cat x y 2>&1 | tee log
```

<sub>(NOTE: If this doesn't do what you want, *edit your question* to include the actual error message you got, and explain clearly how it is different from the result you wanted.)</sub>

Comment: my apologies i made mistake that earlier comment on `cat x y | tee log` worked fine i found the problem on why it didn't, sorry and thanks for the help. you can edit answer so it looks like that.

Comment: @Phantom1421 the earlier command `cat x y | tee log` will not put the error message from `cat` into the file `log`.  The command in my answer will.